# Javascript function use before script included

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have this script:

```
<img src="/images/pic.png" onclick="manage(1);">
<script src="func.js"></script>
```

func.js contains one function manage that shows an alert with the id in the brackets.

If i do like that, i receive an error that the function manage is not defined.

Mention: i'm obligated to use the function and then include the script in the end of the file.

What to do ?

Comment: Are you _sure_ the script defines `manage`? If you put the script above the `img` does it work?

Comment: The browser won't look for a manage function until the image is clicked. The problem is not the location of the script element (at least not as it is shown in the question).

Comment: You can (_should_) attach the click handler to the image in func.js.

Comment: Better explaination:

#html:
<div id="3" name="3">
<img src="image.png" onclick="manage(3);">
</div>
<script src="script.js"></script>

#script.js
function manage( val )
{
var fx = document.getElementById( val );    
  fx.parentNode.removeChild(fx);
}

This throws function manage not defined !

Comment: @ADrianC Are you sure that the script is actually being loaded? Try adding a `console.log()` to it to verify that it is loaded.

Comment: @ADrianC: Use the "edit" link on the question to improve it, rather than posting code to comments. As you can (now) see, it comes out essentially unreadable.

Comment: @ADrianC: That code won't cause that error either, for the same reason Quentin gave above. You need to look elsewhere. Pare it down to an [MCVE](/help/mcve).